# Consumir Api en laravel con grant type Password error de autenticación

Tags: laravel, api, postman, tokens, autenticacion

Estoy tratando de consumir una api con Laravel, pero al querer obtener el token me da un error 401 de no autorizado, con las mismas credenciales puedo obtener el acceso en Postman, pero al hacer la consulta desde mi sistema no me da permiso, esta es mi consulta:

```
$client = new Client();
        $client->request('GET', 'https://api....', ['auth' => [
            username' => 'a',
            'password' => 'a',
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 'a',
            'client_secret' => 'a'
           
            ]]);
```

como decia, en Postman puedo obtener el token:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se en que me estoy equivocando, me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Buenas  ,  si estés intentando realizar outh2.0  , antes de lanzar la petición final tienes que obtener las credenciales de autenticacion , postman lanza la primera petición  por ti cuando lo utilizas , pero al hacer el codigo de php tendrás que hacer las 2 peticiones tu mismo.

Comment: En postman en la parte derecha te da la opción de código y te genera un pequeño snippet de muestra. Mira la versión PHP - Guzzle que seguro te puede dar una idea de que falla. Prueba de poner los headers de autorización en el Client() no en la Request()

Comment: @estrano3 si, efectivamente, estoy haciendo dos peticiones, una para solicitar el token y otra para solicitar la información ya con el token en el header. pero mi problema es que no me aceptan mi solicitud para obtener el token desde mi sistema. Si estoy 'conectando' con la aplicación por que me da un error 401, de no autorizado, como si estuvieran equivocadas mis credenciales, pero están correctas, ya las he verificado muchas veces

Comment: @Pepote en el código que Postman me muestra el token ya esta generado, lo solicito en la sección Authorization, lo obtengo y lo uso, y cuando se hace la solicitud  de la información ya lleva el token, de esto es de lo que me muestra el codigo, pero como te de digo ya va el token 'echo'. lo que necesito es generar el token desde mi sistema

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

La solución fue la siguiente, tenia que enviar las credenciales de esta forma:

```
 $response = $http->post('https....', [
            'auth' => [
                $this->client_id,
                $this->client_secret,
            ],
            'form_params' => [  
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'username' => $this->username,
                'password' => $this->password,
               
            ],
        ]);
```